# Vapor 3 - How to check for similar email before saving object

Tags: swift, rest, vapor, vapor-fluent

I would like to create a route to let users update their data (e.g. changing their email or their username). To make sure a user cannot use the same username as another user, I would like to check if a user with the same username already exists in the database.

I have already made the username unique in the migrations.

I have a user model that looks like this:

```
struct User: Content, SQLiteModel, Migration {
    var id: Int?
    var username: String
    var name: String
    var email: String
    var password: String

    var creationDate: Date?

    // Permissions
    var staff: Bool = false
    var superuser: Bool = false

    init(username: String, name: String, email: String, password: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.creationDate = Date()
    }
}
```

This is the piece of code where I want to use it:

```
func create(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<User> {
    return try req.content.decode(UserCreationRequest.self).flatMap { userRequest in

        // Check if `userRequest.email` already exists
        // If if does -> throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "Email already in use")
        // Else -> Go on with creation

        let digest = try req.make(BCryptDigest.self)
        let hashedPassword = try digest.hash(userRequest.password)
        let persistedUser = User(name: userRequest.name, email: userRequest.email, password: hashedPassword)

        return persistedUser.save(on: req)
    }
}
```

I could do it like this (see next snippet) but it seems a strange option as it requires a lot of nesting when more checks for e.g. uniqueness would have to be performed (for instance in the case of updating a user).

```
func create(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<User> {
    return try req.content.decode(UserCreationRequest.self).flatMap { userRequest in
        let userID = userRequest.email
        return User.query(on: req).filter(\.userID == userID).first().flatMap { existingUser in
            guard existingUser == nil else {
                throw Abort(.badRequest, reason: "A user with this email already exists")
            }

            let digest = try req.make(BCryptDigest.self)
            let hashedPassword = try digest.hash(userRequest.password)
            let persistedUser = User(name: userRequest.name, email: userRequest.email, password: hashedPassword)

            return persistedUser.save(on: req)
        }
    }
}
```

---

As one of the answers suggested I've tried to add Error middleware (see next snippet) but this does not correctly catch the error (maybe I am doing something wrong in the code - just started with Vapor).

```
import Vapor
import FluentSQLite

enum InternalError: Error {
    case emailDuplicate
}

struct EmailDuplicateErrorMiddleware: Middleware {
    func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
        let response: Future<Response>

        do {
            response = try next.respond(to: request)
        } catch is SQLiteError {
            response = request.eventLoop.newFailedFuture(error: InternalError.emailDuplicate)
        }

        return response.catchFlatMap { error in
            if let response = error as? ResponseEncodable {
                do {
                    return try response.encode(for: request)
                } catch {
                    return request.eventLoop.newFailedFuture(error: InternalError.emailDuplicate)
                }
            } else {
                return request.eventLoop.newFailedFuture(error: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you 'used' the middleware in configure.swift?

Comment: I used the `ErrorMiddleware` in configure.swift. I've set breakpoints in the middleware code and discovered that `if let response = error as? ResponseEncodable {` never equals `true` in the case of a unique constraint error. Because of this, `return request.eventLoop.newFailedFuture(error: error)` always gets called.

Comment: Yes, your definition of InternalError doesn't conform to ResponseEncodable. I'll edit my answ3r.

Comment: Thanks! It now correctly returns a error on duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the field `unique` in the model using a `Migration` such as:

```
extension User: Migration {
  static func prepare(on connection: SQLiteConnection) -> Future<Void> {
    return Database.create(self, on: connection) { builder in
      try addProperties(to: builder)
      builder.unique(on: \.email)
    }
  }
}
```

If you use a default `String` as the field type for `email`, then you will need to reduce it as this creates a field `VARCHAR(255)` which is too big for a `UNIQUE` key. I would then use a bit of custom `Middleware` to trap the error that arises when a second attempt to save a record is made using the same email.

```
struct DupEmailErrorMiddleware: Middleware
{
    func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response>
    {
        let response: Future<Response>
        do {
            response = try next.respond(to: request)
        } catch is MySQLError {
            // needs a bit more sophistication to check the specific error
            response = request.eventLoop.newFailedFuture(error: InternalError.dupEmail)
        }
        return response.catchFlatMap
        {
            error in
            if let response = error as? ResponseEncodable
            {
                do
                {
                    return try response.encode(for: request)
                }
                catch
                {
                    return request.eventLoop.newFailedFuture(error: InternalError.dupEmail)
                }
            } else
            {
                return request.eventLoop.newFailedFuture(error: error   )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Your custom error needs to be something like:

```
enum InternalError: Debuggable, ResponseEncodable
{
    func encode(for request: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response>
    {
        let response = request.response()
        let eventController = EventController()
        //TODO make this return to correct view
        eventController.message = reason
        return try eventController.index(request).map
        {
            html in
            try response.content.encode(html)
            return response
        }
    }

    case dupEmail

    var identifier:String
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .dupEmail: return "dupEmail"
        }
    }

    var reason:String
    {
       switch self
       {
            case .dupEmail: return "Email address already used"
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, the actual error is displayed to the user by setting a value in the controller, which is then picked up in the view and an alert displayed. This method allows a general-purpose error handler to take care of displaying the error messages. However, in your case, it might be that you could just create the response in the `catchFlatMap`.

Answer (score 4):

The quick way of doing it is to do something like `User.query(on: req).filter(\.email == email).count()` and check that equals 0 before attempting the save.

However, whilst this will work fine for almost everyone, you still risk edge cases where two users try to register with the same username at the exact same time - the only way to handle this is to catch the save failure, check if it was because the unique constraint on the email and return the error to the user. However the chances of you actually hitting that are pretty rare, even for big apps.

Comment: This line returns a `Future<Int>` (which is logical) but to use it I need a regualr `Int`. How to unpack this Future without for instance using `wait()` which blocks the event loop?

Comment: So the way you've done it above with the search is the same as count basically - you need to have the extra future in there because the query to the DB returns a future. You can use `syncDecode` instead of `decode` to remove a layer of nesting though