# How to raise custom error message in Swift / Vapor?

Tags: swift, vapor

How can I customize error message in `Swift` Tried this:

```swift
catch {
   promise.fail(error: error)
}
```

->

```swift
catch {
   promise.fail(error: AddFBDataAndGetPagesError.invalidFacebookAccessToken)
}
```

It has no effect, same standard error message is received in FE.

Comment: Use the custom error `Middleware` I use as part of my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466181/vapor-3-how-to-check-for-similar-email-before-saving-object